# Wordpress: How to make a subsubdirectory

Tags: links

**I have a multiple word press installations that I am trying to reduce to one.**

Here is what it currently looks like:

```
Installation 1 = www.example.com
Installation 2 = www.example.com/foo
Installation 3 = www.example.com/foo/bar
```

How do I make it into one installation like this:

```
www.example.com/foo/bar
```

Where `/foo` and `/foo/bar` are two different pages.

Optionally: How do I do this:

```
www.example.com/baz/bar
```

Where `/baz`  does not do anything (like a 404) and `/bar` is the actual content.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do these pages contain? Are there normal static pages with content? If so, you can just use pages hierarchy to do this (use page parent attribute).

Comment: How is this question off topic? Godaddy hosts the WordPress installation! I installed it under applications!

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Unfortunately the new pages are not static. They are other blogs.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż They might also need to be three directories down... I am trying to consolidate Word press installations and be able to keep existing customers links valid.

Comment: This question was off topic for [webapps.se] as their community deals with _using_ web-apps (such as WordPress.com, or questions regarding how to use the dashboard of a self-hosted installation) whereas your question is more technical, and regards the actual installation, databases, and WordPress scripts. GoDaddy lists WordPress as an app, but really you are using their tool to install a piece of open-source software. It is these administrative tasks that do not qualify as basic webapp "use."

Comment: All of that said, your question is confusing. Are you asking how to migrate the data from all of your installations into a single WordPress database/site? I recommend against using the language "subdirectory," as `/something` does not necessary indicate the presence of a directory named "something." The page rendered at `http://mywordpresssite.com/categories/cat-pictures` does not actually exist in a "cat-pictures" sub-directory, nor a "categories" one. `/something` and `/categories` are simply components of a URL's path.

Comment: Sorry for my rant, here, but continuing, the title of your question indicates that you wish to know how to create a directory within a directory within a directory, which is certainly not what you appear to be asking. I think your primary question is "How do I merge three different WordPress installations?" but it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create sub directories by making parent pages:

Say you want it like this:

```
example.com/topicnamebutnocontent/informationontopic
```

*Note: `/topicbutnoname` is a page/direcory that has no content.*

---

You can create it this way:

- Make a blank page (it does not have to be blank) E.G. `topicnamebutnocontent`
- Make a page that you want to fill with your content E.G. `informationontopic`
- Set `informationontopic`'s parent page to the blank page E.G. `topicnamebutnocontent`
- Double check that the permalink/address is correct with what you want.

And that should create the directory structure that you want!

Have a great day!

Comment: This answer does not appear to answer the question that you originally posed - only the "optional" portion. Did you somehow migrate your sites, or simply continue forward with three separate installations? Please review our [ask] and [answer] topics in the Help Center to get a better grasp on writing quality questions and answers in our community!

Comment: @boscho Thanks for commenting, your help was appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, as long as you're okay with them all using the same theme (it gets much more complicated if you want them to look different), but you should be able to export the posts from the other two blogs and import them into the one you're keeping.

Then create a "top" page for each purpose and set the posts from the imported blogs under that top page via the Parent function.

The end result would be one site with three distinct areas controlled by the taxonomy.

This does not work if you need to use separate themes, however.

Comment: I have figured out how to do it. I will post the answer in a bit.